# Is Apache mod_evasive really worthful

Tags: apache-2.4, ddos, mod-security

I read an article saying that apache mod_evasive is an old outdated module and does not real protection against Dos attack. After testing a scenario of load requests to a apache webpage it seems like it is really not protecting at all, although the logs indicates that it is functional.

Anyone who have really used mod_evasive module and verified its efficiency could tell if it is worthful or really not?

Comment: You tagged it with DDoS. `mod_evasive` is a simple rate limiter and won't help with a **distributed** DoS from thousands of hosts.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "not protecting at all". Does this mean new requests are not denied by server once the threshold values are reached.

In case you've just enabled the module and not added the configs, default values should take effect. But before that check if the module is actually enabled and getting loaded.

I can confirm it works on Apache 2.4.52